# DLL load failed error with Python while trying to convert .dem files to .grid files

Tags: python, dll, load, gdal

I've been trying to find a free and easy way to convert .dem files to .grid files, and I've been working on getting a python program that was online to do it. I've been getting an error that I don't understand, and looking it up online has shown me that people have gotten this error before, but not necessarily in the context that I'm finding it, so their solutions involve installing different modules that are not the one that I need.

Here is my python installment:

```
Python 3.4.0 (v3.4.0:04f714765c13) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Here is how I installed a module I needed, called osgeo. I followed the steps based on the above python installment, making sure that I used the correct versions for everything:
[Instructions I used](https://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/tutorials/installing-gdal-for-windows)
Following those instructions allowed me to get past an error that osgeo didn't exist, so at least I've made some progress in that aspect.

Here is the code I've been trying to run:

```
import sys
import os
import osgeo.gdal as gd
from gdalconst import GA_ReadOnly, GDT_Byte, GDT_UInt16, GDT_Int16, \
     GDT_UInt32, GDT_Int32, GDT_Float32, GDT_Float64
import struct

# GDAL data types to packt data_types
gd_type = {GDT_Byte:    "b",
           GDT_UInt16:  "H",
           GDT_Int16:   "h",
           GDT_UInt32:  "I",
           GDT_Int32:   "i",
           GDT_Float32: "f",
           GDT_Float64: "d"}
# establish input file
ifilename = r"C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\sample.dem"
# generate output file name 
ofilename = os.path.splitext(ifilename)[0] + ".grid"
# use gdal to read DEM file
idataset = gd.Open(ifilename, GA_ReadOnly)
if idataset is None:
    print("Cannot read input file {}".format(ifilename));
    sys.exit(2)
# get size of dem
cols = idataset.RasterXSize
rows = idataset.RasterYSize
# get and calculate coordinate limits
tr = idataset.GetGeoTransform()
xul = tr[0]
yul = tr[3]
xlr = xul + (cols - 1) * tr[1] 
ylr = yul + (rows - 1) * tr[5]
# write data to binary output
of = open(ofilename, "wb")
of.write(struct.pack("2i", cols, rows))
of.write(struct.pack("4f", xul, ylr, xlr, yul))
band = idataset.GetRasterBand(1)
d = band.ReadRaster(0, 0, cols, rows, cols, rows, band.DataType)
data = struct.unpack(gd_type[band.DataType] * (rows * cols), d)
of.write(struct.pack("f" * (cols * rows), *data))
of.close()
```

Here is my error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Nick/Desktop/demtogrid.py", line 3, in <module>
    import osgeo.gdal as gd
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I've also tried other code from [this forum](https://arsandbox.ucdavis.edu/forums/topic/dem-help/), such as the one by a user named *siki*, but all of my attempts have ended up with the same error as shown in the example above.

Thanks for anyone who helps. Again, it doesn't HAVE to be a python script that does the conversion for me, I just need a free way to convert .dem to .grid, and the typical programs for this like ArcGIS are not free.

Comment: Apparently `osgeo` doesn't seem to be installed correctly. You chose *release-1600-x64...* right? Did you add the **correct** path in your environment? If you run *Python* on your script from a *cmd* console, you open a new one after setting the env var. Let me know if you did all the steps above, or should I investigate it.

Comment: At the website http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php I clicked release-1600-x64-gdal-2-2-3-mapserver-7-0-7 and then GDAL-2.2.3.win-amd64-py3.4.msi was the one I installed. I then followed the rest of those instructions exactly as it said 64-bit should do. I'm running python via pressing F5 while the code is open as a document in python shell (version shown in the original post). Should I be using cmd instead? Would that make a difference with the DLL Load Failed error?

Comment: *edit: I also installed gdal-202-1600-x64-core.msi along with GDAL-2.2.3.win-amd64-py3.4.msi, as the directions stated to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't set your *%PATH%* env var right. I managed to reproduce the problem, and also to fix it. Some of the steps that I took are different than the regular ones, for reasons that I'll explain later:

- There are ~10 *Python* installations on my machine (some installed, some built by me - with different compiler; most of them are *x64*, some are *VEnv*ed, but that shouldn't make any difference), *Python 3.4 x64* (built with compiler *v1.600* - *VStudio 10.0*) is among them
- Saved your code on my computer (*code.py*). Running it, (obviously) failed:

  > ```bat
  > (py34x64_test) E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048854161>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py34x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
  > Traceback (most recent call last):
  >   File "code.py", line 3, in <module>
  >     import osgeo.gdal as gd
  > ImportError: No module named 'osgeo'
  > ```
- Downloaded:

  1. [[GISInternals]: release-1600-x64-gdal-2-2-3-mapserver-7-0-7.zip](http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1600-x64-gdal-2-2-3-mapserver-7-0-7.zip) - Compiled binaries in a single .zip package
  2. [[GISInternals]: GDAL-2.2.3.win-amd64-py3.4.msi](http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1600-x64-gdal-2-2-3-mapserver-7-0-7/GDAL-2.2.3.win-amd64-py3.4.msi) - Installer for the GDAL python bindings (requires to install the GDAL core)
- Unpacked (in the current dir):

  - *#1.* in a dir called ***gdal*** - by simply unzipping it
  - *#2.* in a dir called ***gdal_py*** - by running `msiexec /a GDAL-2.2.3.win-amd64-py3.4.msi TARGETDIR="E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048854161\gdal_py"` (`msiexec`'s **Adminstrative Installation** as shown on [[SuperUser]: How do I extract files from an MSI package?](https://superuser.com/questions/307678/how-do-i-extract-files-from-an-msi-package), check [[MS.Docs]: Command-Line Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/msi/command-line-options) for more details)

    - Because the normal installation places the relevant files in *Python* install dirs, it also mimics them, so the relevant files were actually installed in "*gdal_py\Lib\site-packages*", for simplicity's sake, I moved them 2 folders up (directly in the *gdal_py* dir)
  - I did things this way, because I don't want to pollute my *OS* with *pkg*s that I'm probably only going to use once, so I want these 2 to be only related to this question. Of course this is a source of additional headaches (just kidding :) ), that don't occur in the regular installation process
- Adding *gdal_py* to *%PYTHONPATH%* (not necessary for regular installation of *#2.*, as the files are already in *Python*'s module search path - check the moving operation that I had to do earlier), and running it again, yielded:

  > ```bat
  > (py34x64_test) E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048854161>set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;gdal_py
  >
  > (py34x64_test) E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048854161>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py34x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
  > Traceback (most recent call last):
  >   File "code.py", line 3, in <module>
  >     import osgeo.gdal as gd
  >   File "E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048854161\gdal_py\osgeo\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
  >     _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  >   File "E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048854161\gdal_py\osgeo\__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
  >     _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
  >   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py34x64_test\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
  >     return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  > ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
  > ```
- This is exactly your error. So, it tries to load *_gdal.pyd* and fails, not because it can't find it, but because (some of) its dependencies could not be found (here, the error message is misleading, if the module wouldn't have been found the error would be: `ImportError: No module named '_gdal'`). 
  Below is a picture of *_gdal.pyd* loaded in [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com). Note that the regular *#2.* installation places it under *%PYTHON34X64_INSTALL_DIR%\Lib\site-packages\osgeo* (that's not a real env var, just a path placeholder):

  [image: _gdal.pyd]
- As seen, it depends on *gdal202.dll*. So, when *_gdal.pyd* is imported, the *OS* needs to find all of its dependencies: note that this is done **recursively** (dependencies, dependencies' dependencies, and so on). This is what the *%PATH%* env var setting in the tutorial was about. For me, the simplest way was to add *gdal202.dll* dir (as it is part of *#1.*, that would be *gdal\bin*) to *%PATH%* ([[MS.Docs]: Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order)):

  > ```bat
  > (py34x64_test) E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048854161>set PATH=%PATH%;gdal\bin
  >
  > (py34x64_test) E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048854161>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py34x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
  > ERROR 4: C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\sample.dem: No such file or directory
  > Cannot read input file C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\sample.dem
  > ```
- **It worked**! Well, it didn't quite work, because there are other things in your script that I don't have, but it **successfully** passed this step. Now, there could be errors in the script, that would prevent you to achieve your goal, but those are not related to the current problem.

Comment: Wow, thank you for getting to the same error I've got! So, I went through the gdal folder and found gdal202.dll. I then copied the file, and went to %PATH% (which brought me to my C: folder), and then pasted it in there. However, I ran it and got the same error. Should I have done something else as well? How are your environment variables set up, maybe I screwed them up or something? But yes, the error you made it to is exactly where I want to get because I do have the file at C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\sample.dem so getting to that point would be awesome.

Comment: No, don't move *.dll*s around. Besides, *gdal202.dl* depends on some other *.dll*s in its folder. Simply add its folder to *%PATH%*. It should work (you probably could open a *cmd* console and type `set PATH` there, and paste the output into the question). If you added it to the _**System** variables_, your *PC* would require a restart in order for the change to be visible to running apps.

Comment: So for me, gdal202.dll (and a bunch of other .dll files) is located at C:\Program Files\GDAL (no bin folder). I typed set PATH C:\Program Files\GDAL and got the output "Environment variable PATH C:\Program Files\GDAL is not defined". However, simply typing set PATH shows me a bunch of locations, the first of which is Path=C:\Program Files\GDAL; C:\...other stuff. Am I typing in the wrong thing? Also, thanks for clarifying that I'm not moving any files around.

Comment: You shouldn't place it a the beginning, but at the end of *%PATH%*. The command is `set path` <ENTER>. Also I don't think there should be *SPACE*s between entries ("GDAL; C:\"). Better try it from *Python*: `import os`, `print(os.environ["PATH"])`.

Comment: Typing just set path, followed by restarting my computer worked!!! The file converted! Thank you so much; I've been working on this for quite a while. Thank you!