# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ctypes : The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, ctypes, importerror

Error:
**ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ctypes : The specified module could not be found**

Need: **How to resolve this error? And launch jupyter notebook and use pip from the specific environment?**
It works on other environment.

While trying to launch jupyter notebook or using pip in virtual environment.
I couldn't launch jupyter in the environment "Myenvproject".
It launches on the base environment.

I tried to
`conda uninstall pyzmq`
In the environment.

And reinstall jupyter in "Myenvproject"  Environment but it still doesn't launch.
[Jupyter doesn't launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyQrS.jpg)

Turns out that when I check for
`pip --verison` 
It then also shows the same error
[Can't use pip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwEbX.jpg)

Windows 10
Python 3.10.0(Anaconda, virtual environment)

Comment: Please post the error as text, not an image.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @toyotaSupra I posted the error as text

Comment: @Community How to resolve the ImportError: DLL failed while importing _ctypes

Comment: What does (in a console) output: `dir "C:\Users\shing\anaconda3\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd"`? Also the other environment is also *Python 3.10.0*?

Comment: I just created a fresh environment and it works.

Comment: @CristiFati The console output is in the first image, "Jupyter doesn't launch". The other environment is python 3.9. Jupyter was working good, but a day before this issue, I updated few modules and installed selenium and from next day jupyter won't launch.

Comment: What's the command list you're running and where from?

Answer (score 8):

### 1. Intro

I noticed this question (or very similar / duplicate ones) several times lately, but none of them provides a clear path to consistently run into the issue (environment creation, commands run in order to reach this state). Also, considering the frequency this question is viewed, one could only conclude this is a fairly common problem.
I'm going to post some guidelines to prevent users from running into it, and also some investigation techniques meant to let users know how to get out of it once hit.

**Notes**:

- I **wasn't able to run into this** - well unless purposely messing up the environment
- Error is about *_ctypes.pyd*, but the principle applies to any other *.pyd* (*.dll*)
- Although I'm conducting my investigation on *Win*, concepts also apply to *Nix*
- I am using (at answer date, upgraded constantly from older versions) *Anaconda*:

  - *Navigator 2.4.2*
  - *Conda 23.5.2*
  - *Python 3.9.17* (base environment)

### 2. *CTypes* considerations

[[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) is a library (initially started by Thomas Heller, then adopted by *Python*'s standard library a long long time ago), designed to interact with (mainly, call functions from) *.dll*s (*.so*s) written in other (lower level) languages.
There are tons of examples on the internet, even here on *SO*, I'm going to exemplify a few (of mine):

- [[SO]: Python ctypes, char** and DLL (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75448309/4788546)
- [[SO]: Access OpenSSL FIPS APIs from python ctypes not working (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75890880/4788546)
- [[SO]: How to run a Fortran script with ctypes? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75944691/4788546)
- [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) - a common pitfall especially for the less experienced

*CTypes* uses *LibFFI* ([[GitHub]: libffi/libffi - A portable foreign-function interface library](https://github.com/libffi/libffi) - written mostly in *C* and *ASM*) under the hood.

It consists of 2 parts:

1. The core: written in *C* (which uses *LibFFI*). Located at [[GitHub]: pytgon/cpython - (main) cpython/Modules/_ctypes](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/main/Modules/_ctypes). This does all the magic, and it's an **extension module** ([[Python.Docs]: Extending Python with C or C++](https://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html#extending-python-with-c-or-c)). It's a *.dll* (*.so*) file named ***_ctypes.pyd*** on *Win* (this is how I'm going to reference it), or ***_ctypes*.so*** on *Nix* (check [[Python.PEPs]: PEP 3149 - ABI version tagged .so files](https://peps.python.org/pep-3149) for more naming convention details)
2. The *Python* wrappers. Located at [[GitHub]: pytgon/cpython - (main) cpython/Lib/ctypes](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/main/Lib/ctypes). Provides a *Python* friendly access to the core

The way *_ctypes.pyd* depends on *LibFFI* varies very much on *OS* and *Python* distribution / version.

#### 2.1. *CPython*

On some *OS*es (*Win* included) *LibFFI* code (at least the needed part) was duplicated in *Python* codebase and built into *_ctypes.pyd*. Although it was easier at the beginning, it's not a good practice as it becomes very hard to maintain if one needs to keep the referred software up to date, and also licensing might become a problem. So, since *Python 3.8* they stopped doing that ([[GitHub]: pytgon/cpython - bpo-45022: Pin current libffi build to fixed version in preparation for upcoming update](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/27982), [[GitHub]: pytgon/cpython - bpo-45022: Update libffi to 3.4.2 in Windows build](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/28146)). Differences (check for *libffi_msvc*):

1. [[GitHub]: pytgon/cpython - (**3.7**) cpython/Modules/_ctypes](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.7/Modules/_ctypes)
2. [[GitHub]: pytgon/cpython - (**3.8**) cpython/Modules/_ctypes](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.8/Modules/_ctypes)

This change has some implications:

- Build: *LibFFI* code (*API*) is required on the build machine and *Python* code needs to know where it is (similar to *Linux* world where *libffi-dev* (or equivalent) is required)
- *LibFFI* is built in a stand alone *.dll* (*libffi*.dll*) that *_ctypes.pyd* depends on (and **must be present at runtime** (when the module is loaded)).
  **On *Win*, that *.dll* is shipped by the *Python* installer**

Illustrating the differences on various *OS*es:

- ***Win*** (check [[SO]: How to build a DLL version of libjpeg 9b? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44469099/4788546) (at the end) for *.dll* dependency command details) - *PS* console:

  > ```
  > [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:E:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q073458524]> sopr.bat
  > ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
  >
  > [prompt]>
  > [prompt]> $_CTss = Get-ChildItem 'c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python' -Filter '_ctypes.pyd' -Recurse
  > [prompt]> foreach ($_CTs in $_CTss) {
  > >>     echo $_CTs.FullName
  > >>     Start-Process -Wait -FilePath 'c:\Install\pc064\Depends\DependencyWalkerPolitistTexan\Version\depends.exe' -ArgumentList '-c', '-ot:out.txt', $_CTs.FullName
  > >>     Get-Content 'out.txt' | Select-String 'FFI.*\.DLL$'
  > >> }
  > C:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\02.07.18\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
  > C:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.04.04\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
  > C:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.05.04\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
  > C:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.06.08\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
  > C:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.07.09\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
  > C:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.08\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
  >
  >      [  6] c:\install\pc064\python\python\03.08\dlls\LIBFFI-7.DLL
  > C:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.09\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
  >      [  6] c:\install\pc064\python\python\03.09\dlls\LIBFFI-7.DLL
  > C:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
  >      [  6] c:\install\pc064\python\python\03.10\dlls\LIBFFI-7.DLL
  > C:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.11\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
  >      [  6] c:\install\pc064\python\python\03.11\dlls\LIBFFI-8.DLL
  > ```
- ***OSX***:

  > ```
  > [cristian.fati@cfati-16i2019-0:~/Work/Dev/StackExchange/StackOverflow/q073458524]> ~/sopr.sh
  > ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
  >
  > Running OSX
  > [064bit prompt]>
  > [064bit prompt]> uname -a
  > Darwin cfati-16i2019-0 22.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.5.0: Thu Jun  8 22:22:22 PDT 2023; root:xnu-8796.121.3~7/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
  > [064bit prompt]>
  > [064bit prompt]> for g in 7 8 9 10 11; do _CTS=$(python3.${g} -c "import ctypes;print(_ctypes.__file__)"); echo ${_CTS}; otool -L ${_CTS} | grep ffi; done
  > /usr/local/cellar/python@3.7/3.7.16/frameworks/python.framework/versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  > /usr/local/cellar/python@3.8/3.8.17_1/frameworks/python.framework/versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-38-darwin.so
  >    /usr/lib/libffi.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 30.0.0)
  > /usr/local/cellar/python@3.9/3.9.17_1/frameworks/python.framework/versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-39-darwin.so
  >    /usr/lib/libffi.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 30.0.0)
  > /usr/local/cellar/python@3.10/3.10.12_1/frameworks/python.framework/versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-310-darwin.so
  >    /usr/lib/libffi.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 30.0.0)
  > /usr/local/cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/frameworks/python.framework/versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-311-darwin.so
  >    /usr/lib/libffi.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 30.0.0)
  > ```
- ***Linux*** - *Ubuntu*:

  > ```
  > (qaic-env) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackExchange/StackOverflow/q073458524]> ~/sopr.sh 
  > ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
  >
  > [064bit prompt]> 
  > [064bit prompt]> uname -a
  > Linux cfati-5510-0 6.2.0-37-generic #38~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Nov  2 18:01:13 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  > [064bit prompt]> 
  > [064bit prompt]> for g in 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12; do _CTS=$(python3.${g} -c "import _ctypes;print(_ctypes.__file__)"); echo ${_CTS}; ldd ${_CTS} | grep ffi; done
  > /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  >     libffi.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7 (0x00007ff1fb7d1000)
  > /usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  >     libffi.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7 (0x00007f0bf4ec5000)
  > /usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  >     libffi.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8 (0x00007fc2a3ae6000)
  > /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  >     libffi.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8 (0x00007f32b6176000)
  > /usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  >     libffi.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8 (0x00007f40e590a000)
  > /usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  >     libffi.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8 (0x00007f20bcbc7000)
  > /usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  >     libffi.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8 (0x00007f01a5555000)
  > /usr/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  >     libffi.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8 (0x00007f4a95e2d000)
  > ```
- ***Linux*** - *CentOS* (*Docker*):

  > ```
  > [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q073458524]> ~/sopr.sh
  > ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
  >
  > [064bit prompt]>
  > [064bit prompt]> cat /etc/os-release | grep PRODUCT
  > REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
  > REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
  > [064bit prompt]>
  > [064bit prompt]> for g in 2.7 3.6; do _CTS=$(python${g} -c "import _ctypes;print(_ctypes.__file__)"); echo ${_CTS}; ldd ${_CTS} | grep ffi; done
  > /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
  >     libffi.so.6 => /lib64/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f6529d71000)
  > /usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  >     libffi.so.6 => /lib64/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f1085acc000)
  > ```

**Couple of words** about *Nix* (*Linux*) where a similar error occurs.

- *Ubuntu*:

  Running the command `ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi*.so* | xargs dpkg -S` will output 3 packages owning files of interest: *LibFFI 8*, *LibFFI 7*, *LibFFI-Dev*.

  Depending on *Python* version, the appropriate package should be installed (3<sup>rd</sup> one isn't required, but adding it just in case):

  **`apt install libffi8 libffi7 libffi-dev`**
- *CentOS*:

  Following the same steps (different tools) yields:

  **`yum install libffi libffi-devel`**

More details can be found at [[SO]: No module named '_ctypes'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63996623/4788546).

#### 2.2. *Anaconda*

Naturally, *Anaconda*'s distribution of *Python* follows *CPython*, but they took things a bit further.

> ```
> (base) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q073458524]> :: ------- Anaconda Prompt -------
> (base) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q073458524]> cd /d f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version
>
> (base) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> :: Reactivate base to have active environment in prompt
> [prompt]> conda deactivate & conda activate base
>
> (base) [prompt]> :: ------- Anaconda Prompt (still) -------
> (base) [prompt]> conda env list
> # conda environments:
> #
>                          F:\Install\pc032\Intel\OneAPI\Version\intelpython\python3.7
>                          F:\Install\pc032\Intel\OneAPI\Version\intelpython\python3.7\envs\2021.1.1
> base                  *  f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version
> py_pc032_030602_00       f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc032_030602_00
> py_pc064_030610_00       f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030610_00
> py_pc064_030704_00       f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030704_00
> py_pc064_030716_00       f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030716_00
> py_pc064_030800_00       f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030800_00
> py_pc064_030808_00       f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030808_00
> py_pc064_030817_00       f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030817_00
> py_pc064_030900_00       f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030900_00
> py_pc064_030917_00       f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030917_00
> py_pc064_030917_01       f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030917_01
> py_pc064_031000_00       f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031000_00
> py_pc064_031006_00       f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031006_00
> py_pc064_031012_00       f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031012_00
> py_pc064_031012_01       f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031012_01
> py_pc064_031104_00       f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031104_00
>
>
> (base) [prompt]>
> (base) [prompt]> :: Search environments for _ctypes.pyd
> (base) [prompt]> dir /B /S "envs\*_ctypes.pyd"
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc032_030602_00\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030610_00\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030610_00\DLLs\instrumented\_ctypes.pyd
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030704_00\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030704_00\DLLs\instrumented\_ctypes.pyd
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030716_00\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030800_00\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030800_00\DLLs\instrumented\_ctypes.pyd
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030808_00\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030817_00\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030900_00\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030917_00\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030917_01\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031000_00\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031006_00\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031012_00\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031012_01\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031104_00\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
>
> (base) [prompt]>
> (base) [prompt]> :: Search environments for the FFI dll
> (base) [prompt]> dir /B /S "envs\*ffi*.dll"
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030800_00\DLLs\libffi-7.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030808_00\DLLs\libffi-7.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030817_00\DLLs\libffi-7.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030817_00\Library\bin\ffi-7.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030817_00\Library\bin\ffi-8.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030817_00\Library\bin\ffi.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030900_00\DLLs\libffi-7.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030917_00\DLLs\libffi-7.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_030917_01\DLLs\libffi-7.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031000_00\Library\bin\ffi-7.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031000_00\Library\bin\ffi-8.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031000_00\Library\bin\ffi.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031006_00\Library\bin\ffi-7.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031006_00\Library\bin\ffi-8.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031006_00\Library\bin\ffi.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031012_00\Library\bin\ffi-7.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031012_00\Library\bin\ffi-8.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031012_00\Library\bin\ffi.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031012_01\Library\bin\ffi-7.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031012_01\Library\bin\ffi-8.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031012_01\Library\bin\ffi.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031104_00\Library\bin\ffi-7.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031104_00\Library\bin\ffi-8.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031104_00\Library\bin\ffi.dll
> ```

As seen, there are 2 types of *.dll*s:

1. *libffi*.dll* (located in the same directory as *_ctypes.pyd*)
2. *ffi*.dll* (located in *..\Library\bin* relative to *_ctypes.pyd*)

**I discovered empirically** what I'm stating here (I don't have an official source - at least not yet).

*#1.* comes from *CPython* (also, older versions don't have the *libffi*.dll*), and are distributed by the *Python* package.
*#2.* comes from *LibFFI* package (was split out of *Python* - it now offers a greater granularity, separate upgrades, ...). There are 3 different *.dll*s (*ffi.dll*, *ffi-7.dll*, *ffi-8.dll*), but they are just copies (don't know why weren't they *SymLink*ed). This seems to be the newer approach, **preferred by newer *Python* versions** (I think starting with *v3.10*). Worth mentioning *v3.8.17* which seems to contain both forms<sup>***1***</sup>.
Scanning inside packages, **the paths match** (once the leading environment part is dropped):

> ```
> (base) [prompt]> :: ------- Anaconda Prompt (still) -------
> (base) [prompt]> dir /B /S "pkgs\*ffi*.dll"
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\pkgs\libffi-3.4.2-hd77b12b_4\Library\bin\ffi-7.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\pkgs\libffi-3.4.2-hd77b12b_4\Library\bin\ffi-8.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\pkgs\libffi-3.4.2-hd77b12b_4\Library\bin\ffi.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\pkgs\libffi-3.4.2-hd77b12b_6\Library\bin\ffi-7.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\pkgs\libffi-3.4.2-hd77b12b_6\Library\bin\ffi-8.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\pkgs\libffi-3.4.2-hd77b12b_6\Library\bin\ffi.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\pkgs\libffi-3.4.4-hd77b12b_0\Library\bin\ffi-7.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\pkgs\libffi-3.4.4-hd77b12b_0\Library\bin\ffi-8.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\pkgs\libffi-3.4.4-hd77b12b_0\Library\bin\ffi.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\pkgs\python-3.8.0-hff0d562_2\DLLs\libffi-7.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\pkgs\python-3.8.12-h6244533_0\DLLs\libffi-8.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\pkgs\python-3.8.13-h6244533_0\DLLs\libffi-7.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\pkgs\python-3.8.17-h1aa4202_0\DLLs\libffi-7.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\pkgs\python-3.8.5-h5fd99cc_1\DLLs\libffi-7.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\pkgs\python-3.8.8-hdbf39b2_5\DLLs\libffi-7.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\pkgs\python-3.9.0-h6244533_2\DLLs\libffi-7.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\pkgs\python-3.9.12-h6244533_0\DLLs\libffi-7.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\pkgs\python-3.9.16-h6244533_2\DLLs\libffi-7.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\pkgs\python-3.9.17-h1aa4202_0\DLLs\libffi-7.dll
> f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\pkgs\python-3.9.17-h6244533_0\DLLs\libffi-7.dll
> ```

### 3. The error

Although, the error mentions *_ctypes.pyd*, it's not necessary that **that** *.dll* is problematic (and often isn't), but one of its dependencies (or dependencies dependencies, ...). Even if it's about a different error, [[SO]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57297745/4788546) is a thorough investigation, and it's the same principle (this error is mentioned somewhere at the end).
While we're here, it probably also worth reading:

- [[SO]: Can't import dll module in Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59333711/4788546)
- [[SO]: DLL load failed error with Python while trying to convert .dem files to .grid files (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48855655/4788546)
- [[SO]: Load a DLL with dependencies in Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61776284/4788546)

#### 3.1. Avoiding it

There are a bunch of generic (common sense) rules that should keep anyone following them out of trouble. Needless to say that if there's a bug in one of the packages (out of user's control), the error might still pop up:

- Be aware of the *Python* instance being used (active): [[SO]: How to install a package for a specific Python version on Windows 10? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57883242/4788546)
- Work from *Conda* prompt
- Only use *Conda* managed environments: [[Conda.Docs]: Managing environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#managing-environments). Technically things could work if using other types (*VEnv*, plain *CPython*, ...), but there's pretty high chance of running into trouble (and if you're reading this, you probably shouldn't)
- Activate an environment and only use that one. Avoid mixing them ([[SO]: PyCharm doesn't recognize installed module (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73363599/4788546)). Activation sets some *env* *var*s specific to that environment:

  > ```
  > (base) [prompt]> :: ------- Anaconda Prompt (still) -------
  > (base) [prompt]> :: --- PATH in active (base) environment ---
  > (base) [prompt]> echo off & (for %g in ("%PATH:;=" "%") do (echo %~g)) & echo on
  > f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version
  > f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\Library\mingw-w64\bin
  > f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\Library\usr\bin
  > f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\Library\bin
  > f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\Scripts
  > f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\bin
  > f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\condabin
  > C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
  > C:\WINDOWS\System32
  > C:\WINDOWS
  > C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
  > C:\Install\pc064\Docker\Docker\Version\Docker\resources\bin
  > C:\Program Files\dotnet
  > e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current\Win
  > e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts
  > C:\Users\cfati\.dotnet\tools
  > .
  >
  > (base) [prompt]>
  > (base) [prompt]> :: --- Activate Python 3.10.12 environment ---
  > (base) [prompt]> conda activate py_pc064_031012_00
  >
  > (py_pc064_031012_00) [prompt]> :: --- PATH in active (py_pc064_031012_00) environment ---
  > (py_pc064_031012_00) [prompt]> echo off & (for %g in ("%PATH:;=" "%") do (echo %~g)) & echo on
  > f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031012_00
  > f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031012_00\Library\mingw-w64\bin
  > f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031012_00\Library\usr\bin
  > f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031012_00\Library\bin
  > f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031012_00\Scripts
  > f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_031012_00\bin
  > f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\condabin
  > C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
  > C:\WINDOWS\System32
  > C:\WINDOWS
  > C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
  > C:\Install\pc064\Docker\Docker\Version\Docker\resources\bin
  > C:\Program Files\dotnet
  > e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current\Win
  > e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts
  > C:\Users\cfati\.dotnet\tools
  > .
  > ```

  It's easy to see that having variables set for an environment, but using another is a recipe for disaster
- Prefer *Conda* packages (and pay attention to the channels they come from) over *PIP*. Although the latter will most likely work, they are mainly tested for *CPython*, and might miss some *Anaconda* specifics

#### 3.2. Troubleshooting

There are ways of getting out of the error. [[SO]: Discover missing module using command-line ("DLL load failed" error) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74883130/4788546) contains a number of tools able to help pinpointing a missing / bad dependency. In our case:

> ```
> (py_pc064_031012_00) [prompt]> :: ------- Anaconda Prompt (still) -------
> (py_pc064_031012_00) [prompt]> "f:\Install\pc064\LucasG\DependencyWalkerPolitistTexan\Version\DependenciesGui.exe" "envs\%CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV%\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd"
>
> (py_pc064_031012_00) [prompt]> conda deactivate & conda activate py_pc064_030817_00
>
> (py_pc064_030817_00) [prompt]> "f:\Install\pc064\LucasG\DependencyWalkerPolitistTexan\Version\DependenciesGui.exe" "envs\%CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV%\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd"
> ```

- *Python 3.10.12* (containing and using *LibFFI* *.dll*s from *LibFFI* package (newer)):

  [image: Img0]
- *Python 3.8.17* <sup>***(1)***</sup> (containing *LibFFI* *.dll*s from both packages, but using the ones from *Python* (older)):

  [image: Img1]

As seen, the dependency tree (custom dependents at least) is simple. In this case it's a 99% chance that *ffi.dll* is missing. That can be fixed by executing (in the environment):

##### `conda install libffi`

Manually taking care of things (copying the files) is also an option, but it might come to bite in the ass at a later time.

Worth paying attention to the ***PATH*** *env* *var*, as it might contain directories with the same *.dll* names (before the "good" ones). Check [[SO]: Can't get FontForge to import as a module in a custom Python script (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75728665/4788546) (*Update #0* section) for a similar problem.

In some cases the error might be triggered by some other factors (disk failure, manually deletion, faulty packages, ...), and in those cases recreating the environment could solve it.
Some other times, upgrading the environment or *Conda* ([[Anaconda.Docs]: Updating from older versions](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/update-version/#updating-from-older-versions)) might help.

If the error is stubborn and just won't go away, reinstalling *Anaconda* altogether might be required, but only use that after lots of considerations and **as a last resort**.

### 4. Summary

If reaching this situation, here's what to do in order to get out of it:

- Search *_ctypes.pyd* dependencies and if missing install (inside the environment) the package that owns them (typically):

  ```
  conda install libffi
  ```
- If *_ctypes.pyd* is missing, reinstall its owning package:

  ```
  conda install python
  ```
- One could also copy (unpack) the files **from the right package, into the right (environment) paths**, but that's for experienced users only
- Check *PATH* *env* *var*, as it might contain paths with files (*.dll*s) interfering with the "right" ones
- Upgrade / recreate the environment
- Upgrade *Conda*
- Reinstall *Anaconda* (**!!! will lose all environments !!!**)

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue too.

Copying **libffi-7.dll** from `\Python310\DLLs` to my env folder fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just uninstalled the environment and reinstalled Anaconda, now it works properly.

Comment: I had this  misleading error aka "import" issue also. I guess it came from installing (slightly diff versions of packages due to) using several diff. conda channels. 
so best to stick with 1 channel only.

try: 
- 1 conda activate *the env*, even if cmd prm  says it is activated
- 2 conda update conda (base and specific env)

Answer (score 1):

I had this misleading error aka "import" issue also.
I guess it came from installing (slightly diff. versions of packages due to) using several diff. conda channels. so it is best to stick with 1 channel only.

try:

1. conda activate the env, even if cmd prm says it is activated
2. conda update conda (base)
3. conda install / update package (specific env)
4. When a package is installed via pip in a conda env, and updated via conda, it results in the same error message shown. => pip install package_name --upgrade

Answer (score 0):

So I add this problem in vcpkg after installing Anaconda:

```
G:\vcpkg_common\downloads\tools\python>G:\vcpkg_common\downloads\tools\python\python-3.11.5-x64\python.exe
Python 3.11.5 (tags/v3.11.5:cce6ba9, Aug 24 2023, 14:38:34) [MSC v.1936 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import _ctypes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ctypes: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
```

I deliberately changed `CWD` since if I am in the same directory as the python I want to use everything works as expected.

Supplying the `-E` option to python makes it work:

```
G:\vcpkg_common\downloads\tools\python>G:\vcpkg_common\downloads\tools\python\python-3.11.5-x64\python.exe -E
Python 3.11.5 (tags/v3.11.5:cce6ba9, Aug 24 2023, 14:38:34) [MSC v.1936 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import _ctypes
>>> exit()
```

However the `-E` option shouldn't do anything since there is no relevant environment variable being set:

```
G:\vcpkg_common\downloads\tools\python>set | findstr PY

G:\vcpkg_common\downloads\tools\python>
```

Looking at sys.path however reveals:

```
>>> sys.path
['', 'G:\\vcpkg_common\\downloads\\tools\\python\\python-3.11.5-x64\\python311.zip', 'C:\\Python\\anaconda3\\Lib', 'C:\\Python\\anaconda3\\DLLs', 'G:\\vcpkg_common\\downloads\\tools\\python\\python-3.11.5-x64', 'G:\\vcpkg_common\\downloads\\tools\\python\\python-3.11.5-x64\\Lib', 'C:\\Users\\neumann\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python311\\site-packages']
```

in the error case and

```
>>> sys.path
['', 'G:\\vcpkg_common\\downloads\\tools\\python\\python-3.11.5-x64\\python311.zip', 'G:\\vcpkg_common\\downloads\\tools\\python\\python-3.11.5-x64', 'G:\\vcpkg_common\\downloads\\tools\\python\\python-3.11.5-x64\\Lib', 'C:\\Users\\neumann\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python311\\site-packages']
```

in the working case. To the error case is trying to load the DLLs from the anaconda location since the its paths hare earlier than the builtin paths leading to the observed error.

After searching through the registry I found:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.11\PythonPath
```

which seems to be responsible for breaking parallel installs.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone Hello. In my case, this helped to solve the problem:

1. Activate your env
2. **conda install libffi**

After that pyinstaller build my exe file without error

And you need to downgrade pyInstaller version
pip uninstall pyinstaller
pip install pyinstaller==5.11
or used this link
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip