# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes' when installing scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, linux, web-scraping, ctypes

Well, I was installing scrapy and I encountered an issue with a _ctypes missing module.I thought it was a problem with my python installation but it wasn't.I reinstalled python and the same issue occurred.I also tried to run

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

but nothing worked.
This is the erro that displayed when I run `scrapy` on my terminal.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wycliffekibet/.pyenv/versions/3.11.2/bin/scrapy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
             ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/wycliffekibet/.pyenv/versions/3.11.2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 138, in execute
    cmds = _get_commands_dict(settings, inproject)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/wycliffekibet/.pyenv/versions/3.11.2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 65, in _get_commands_dict
    cmds = _get_commands_from_module("scrapy.commands", inproject)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/wycliffekibet/.pyenv/versions/3.11.2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 42, in _get_commands_from_module
    for cmd in _iter_command_classes(module):
  File "/home/wycliffekibet/.pyenv/versions/3.11.2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 29, in _iter_command_classes
    for module in walk_modules(module_name):
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/wycliffekibet/.pyenv/versions/3.11.2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 106, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/wycliffekibet/.pyenv/versions/3.11.2/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/wycliffekibet/.pyenv/versions/3.11.2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/commands/parse.py", line 13, in <module>
    from scrapy.utils import display
  File "/home/wycliffekibet/.pyenv/versions/3.11.2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/utils/display.py", line 5, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/home/wycliffekibet/.pyenv/versions/3.11.2/lib/python3.11/ctypes/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
```

I reinstalled python and it didn't work.

Comment: Have you reinstalled the interpreter **after** installing libffi? `sudo apt-get --reinstall install libffi-dev && sudo ldconfig && pyenv uninstall 3.11.2 && pyenv install 3.11.2`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76791146/4788546 might help.