# virtualenv gives error when use pip list: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ctypes:

Tags: python, virtualenv, ctypes, importerror

I ctreated a virtualenv, activated it. I try to run **pip list** and it gives the following error:

```
$ pip list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "D:\development\VENV_VWAP_3_11\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "D:\development\VENV_VWAP_3_11\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "D:\development\VENV_VWAP_3_11\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "D:\development\VENV_VWAP_3_11\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.build_env import get_runnable_pip
  File "D:\development\VENV_VWAP_3_11\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\build_env.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.spinners import open_spinner
  File "D:\development\VENV_VWAP_3_11\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\spinners.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import get_indentation
  File "D:\development\VENV_VWAP_3_11\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\logging.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
  File "D:\development\VENV_VWAP_3_11\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 44, in <module>
    from pip._internal.locations import get_major_minor_version
  File "D:\development\VENV_VWAP_3_11\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\locations\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import _sysconfig
  File "D:\development\VENV_VWAP_3_11\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\locations\_sysconfig.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .base import change_root, get_major_minor_version, is_osx_framework
  File "D:\development\VENV_VWAP_3_11\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\locations\base.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils import appdirs
  File "D:\development\VENV_VWAP_3_11\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\appdirs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import platformdirs as _appdirs
  File "D:\development\VENV_VWAP_3_11\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\platformdirs\__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    PlatformDirs = _set_platform_dir_class()  #: Currently active platform
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\development\VENV_VWAP_3_11\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\platformdirs\__init__.py", line 26, in _set_platform_dir_class
    from pip._vendor.platformdirs.windows import Windows as Result
  File "D:\development\VENV_VWAP_3_11\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\platformdirs\windows.py", line 4, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "C:\Users\Trader\anaconda3\pkgs\python-3.11.5-he1021f5_0\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ctypes: Не найден указанный модуль.
(VENV_VWAP_3_11)
```

I've tried to reinstall anaconda and pip:
**python -m pip install --upgrade pip** and **python -m pip install --force-reinstall pip** but it gives me similar errors.

**pip list** works when I am not in vertualevn

It works on another computer.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Could it be a duplicate of [\[SO\]: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing \_ctypes : The specified module could not be found (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76791146/4788546)?