While running import pandas as pd in python3.10.9 terminal, getting No module ctypes. How to fix it?

import ctypes  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ctypes/init.py",
line 8, in    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'

Python 3.10.9 (main, May 28 2024, 09:54:48) on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
import pandas as pd

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (   File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pandas.core.dtypes.dtypes import (   File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/dtypes.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pandas.errors import PerformanceWarning   File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/errors/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import ctypes   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'


https://stackoverflow.com/a/76791146/4788546 contains a paragraph about Nix. Maybe it helps.

What OS/distro are you on? How did you install Python?
